# Can three reference images be used in 3DS Max when car modeling?

Tags: 3ds-max

I was wondering if it is possible to model a car with only the front, back and side reference images in 3DS Max?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and this method is how I typically do my models if someone hands me a sketch and they want it rendered in 3D.  If i recall, since it has been awhile, its referenced as creating a plane.  A word of advise, just do half the car and then duplicate the model as seen below.  I would separate the views and lock them accordingly similar to this pictures found from a Google Search:

[image]

[image]

A few searches on Youtube will generate many tutorials:

- [Photoshop & 3ds max Tutorial: Blueprint Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ox0sktO4QwI)
- [Modeling a car in 3ds max - Episode 1 - Creating Blueprints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_rUgi6KLow)
- [How to model a car in 3DS MAX - 1 Intro and Preparing the blueprints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhms0zefJ1s)